# Explain the options for npm list [[@<scope>/]<pkg> ...]

Tags: node.js, npm

Please explain the options for the `scope` mentioned in the following command using a couple of EXAMPLES:

```
npm list [[@<scope>/]<pkg> ...]
```

The [docs for this command](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls) does not provide a direct explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's described here well enough :
[Scoped Packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope).

Scopes basically help in grouping similar npm packages together. Each scope will have a directory with the scope's name under node_modules and packages that come under the scope inside it.

In your example, if a scope is given it lists the packages under that particular scope, i.e. under `node_modules/<@scope>/`.